# SFML accessing array inside std::vector

Tags: c++, sfml

In class A I have:

```
class A{
A(){};
 std::vector<sf::Vertex[2]> lines{ 5 };
};
```

And I somehow need to access sf::Vertex 0 and 1 of all the line objects in std::vector. The SFML documentation states on lines:

```
sf::Vertex line[] =
{
sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(10, 10)),
sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(150, 150))  
};
```

I tried many things, but syntax just doesn't work out, from this:

std::vector lines{ {Vertex(100,100),Vertex( 300,300)},... };
to this:

```
A(){
lines[0]->sf::Vertex[0] = (100,100);
...};
```

But it just doesn't work out. What's the proper syntax?

Comment: When something "doesn't work out", it is a good idea to think about **how** it doesn't work out. Did you have some particular expectation about the behaviour? How did the behaviour differ?

Comment: @eerorika I don't think there is any behavior to talk about, since he can't find the right syntax to get past the compilation errors.

Comment: @super well, if the behaviour of the compiler is to show an error, then they should tell us what that error is, rather than keep it a secret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array is not a valid element type for a vector (or any other standard Container). It doesn't satisfy the requirement of being Erasable. You can instead use a class that has the array as a member. The standard library has a template for such array wrapper: `std::vector<std::array<sf::Vertex, 2>>`.

Comment: Consider also making a dedicated `struct` containing two `sf::Vertex`

Comment: @KABoissonneault That's a good approach unless the elements of the array need to be iterable.

Comment: Ok, but what's the syntax for accesing the individual `sf::Vertex`?

Comment: @yomag1234 `lines[0][0]`